# Can I simulate game pad button presses with Java's Robot class (Java.awt.robot)?

Tags: java, arduino, keyevent, awtrobot, rxtx

I'm using an Arduino Uno to hook a (genuine) SNES controller to a computer via USB or Bluetooth.

The Arduino captures the controller's button presses and releases using the [snespad library](http://code.google.com/p/nespad/).  It communicates button presses and releases as characters (e.g. 'a' for pressing A, 'A' for releasing 'A').  Next, a Java program listens to the serial output using the [rxtx library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  Finally, a [Java robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) simulates key presses using the [keyPress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29) and [keyRelease](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyRelease%28int%29).

Unfortunately, this approach has a few drawbacks.  The main issue is key mapping.  I kind of arbitrarily decided which buttons would be which keyboard keys.

Java doesn't appear to have any game pad [KeyEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).  When I say "game pad KeyEvent," I mean something like what the Android SDK has: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html (ctrl+f "game pad" or "button".)

My question is, is there a way to simulate game pad button presses instead of keystrokes using Java's robot class?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just press control and 'f' using the Robot?

Comment: Sorry.  I was saying if you search for "game pad" or "button" on that web page, you'll find the buttons included the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

USING THE ROBOT CLASS IN JAVA

You can create virtual keypresses/releases in the following way...

```
Robot robo=new Robot();
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
//don't forget to release it else you'll land up in infinite loop
robo.KeyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

cheers

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to easily from my expierience the gamepad buttons are mapped to keyboard buttons the only mapping i know it i,j,k,l go to looking around and w,a,s,d go to moving around